# How to handle byte strings in Numba?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numba

What is the proper way to handle byte strings (`b'abc'`) with Numba? According to its documentation it handles Unicode strings similar to Python, with underlying memory representation compatible with Python (1,2,4 bytes with an apropriate tag withing the string object).

Numba has one string type: `nb.types.unicode_type` defined. Additionally conversion methods with encoding/decoding (i.e. `str(x, 'utf-8')`, `string.decode()`) are unvailable with Numba.

I want to use single-byte strings as keys in a typed dict, but I struggle with this error:

```py
    d = numba.typed.Dict.empty(
        key_type = numba.types.unicode_type,
        value_type = numba.int64,
    )
    d[b'xyz'] = 1     # error
```

is throwing an error:

```bash
No implementation of function Function(<built-in function setitem>) found for signature:
 
 >>> setitem(DictType[unicode_type,int64]<iv=None>, readonly bytes(uint8, 1d, C), Literal[int](1))
```

[Numba documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html#str) claims it is handling strings in the same way as Python:

> The in-memory representation is the same as was introduced in Python
> 3.4, with each string having a tag to indicate whether the string is using a 1, 2, or 4 byte character width in memory

Is there some proper way to handle those single-byte strings with Numba types?

Answer (score 0):

So far I managed to solve this issue with custom conversion code. It works with Python byte strings as well as Numpy byte string types (`Sx`):

```py
@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def btostr(x):
    return ''.join([chr(x[i]) for i in range(len(x))])

# ...
d[btostr(b'abc')] = 1
```

I am not sure is this the most efficient way to handle them?

Working example:

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def btostr(x):
    return ''.join([chr(x[i]) for i in range(len(x))])

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def gen(arr):
    d = nb.typed.Dict.empty(
        key_type=nb.types.unicode_type,
        value_type=nb.int64)

    for i, v in enumerate(arr):
        d[btostr(v)] = i        
    
    return d

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def test(arr, d):
    for i, v in enumerate(arr):
        print(i, " : ", v, " -> ", d[btostr(v)])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr = np.array([b'abc', b'xyz', b'yuunb', b'abcd', b'abcde', b'ab']) # inferred type 'S5'
    d = gen(arr)

    test(arr, d)
```

Result:

```bash
0  :  b'abc'  ->  0
1  :  b'xyz'  ->  1
2  :  b'yuunb'  ->  2
3  :  b'abcd'  ->  3
4  :  b'abcde'  ->  4
5  :  b'ab'  ->  5
```